# Antergos Install

Tags: boot, disk, gtk, antergos

I have always had trouble installing Antergos.

One time, after messing around for days, the installer completed and I was able to have Antergos on my system.

Now I have an SSD and I want to transfer all my files to the SSD. Somehow, everything got saved to 2 drives on the computer. It looks like half of the boot is on one and everything else is on the other. I took out the second drive; now I cannot boot back into Antergos.

Because of these issues, I decided to do a fresh install of Antergos on my SSD.

I'm having serious trouble with the install disk I made a while ago (my computer cannot boot off USBs for some reason). On the very rare chance that it actually loads the desktop (problem 1), when I try to install, I get the `Cannot create package list` error (problem 2). Yes, cnchi seems to be updated. When I reinstall it I get a Gtk error that it cannot connect to the display.

How can I get the disk to work, and what's up with the package list problem?